# What is $\int F(x)d(f(x)) \text{ if } F'(x) = f(x)$?

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

Consider the standard normal distribution with cdf F(x) and pdf f(x). What is $\int_0^\infty F(x)d(f(x))$?

In context this is a required step when finding the expectation of rank statistic $E(X_{(3)}), n=3$. The next step in solution relates the asked integral to $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-u^2} }{{2\pi}}du$. How did we get there? What is the intuition of integrating a cdf w.r.t. its pdf in general?

Comment: Maybe integration by parts is useful...

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla setting u and v' to what? letting u = F(x) and du/dx still leaves an x in the integral which cannot be expressed in terms of u.

Comment: $u = F, dv = df\implies vdu = f^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the hint by  Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla:
$$\int_0^\infty F(x) d(f(x))
= [F(x) f(x)]_{x=0}^\infty - \int_0^\infty (f(x))^2 \, dx.$$

The integral on the right-hand side is $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{2\pi} \, dx$. (The "$u$" in your solution is not the "$u$" in the integration by parts.)